# Update selected failed

Tags: acumatica

I use this code to open another screen in SO301000

```
    public virtual IEnumerable EcrListemodele(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        var cmdencours = TransactionsOrder.Current;
        if (cmdencours==null) return adapter.Get();

        ZMODELEFILTER.Current.Immatriculation=cmdencours.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>().UsrImmatriculation;
        ZMODELEFILTER.AskExt();
           foreach (ZMODELE un_modele in SOZmodele.Select())
                {
                   if (un_modele.Selected == true)
                    {
                    cmdencours.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>().Usrlistmodele=un_modele.Modele;
                    cmdencours.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>().Usrlistpiece=un_modele.Piece;
                    TransactionsOrder.Update(cmdencours);

                   }
                }
         //}

        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

I have this error when I select one option
[image]

[image]

Thanks, Xavier

Comment: Please add ZMODELE DAC and data view delegate for SOZmodele if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the audit fields use the proper attributes. For example, CreatedByID uses:

```
        #region CreatedByID
        public abstract class createdByID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<createdByID>
        {
        }
        protected Guid? _CreatedByID;
        [PXDBCreatedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? CreatedByID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._CreatedByID;
            }
            set
            {
                this._CreatedByID = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

The attributes you would want to use on the respective fields are:

- PXDBCreatedByID
- PXDBCreatedByScreenID
- PXDBCreatedDateTime
- PXDBLastModifiedByID
- PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID
- PXDBLastModifiedDateTime
- PXDBTimestamp